# Compile error with type families, GADTs and named records

Tags: haskell, gadt, type-families

In the following code, `T1` and `T2` compile fine, but `T3` fails:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}

type family F a

data T1 b where
  T1 :: a -> T1 (F a)

data T2 b where
  T2 :: { x2 :: a } -> T2 a

data T3 b where
  T3 :: { x3 :: a } -> T3 (F a)
```

I'm trying to understand why. `T3` is just `T1` but with a named record. This doesn't seem to be all that special, as one could use constructor syntax to extract it anyway.

These examples probably look silly, but in my code there is a constraint on `a`, e.g. `(Show a)`, so these values can be used when they're extracted.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's forget about `T2` and `T3`, and just try to define an extractor function for `T1`. What should the type be?

```
x1 :: ???
x1 (T1 a) = a
```

Well, you might guess `x1 :: T1 (F a) -> a`. But that's not right, and if you try it then you will get the same error you got for defining `T3`.

The problem is that if someone hands you a `T1 T`, and you happen to know a type `A` such that `F A` is `T`, you cannot conclude that the `T1 T` contains a value of type `A`, since it could instead contain another type `B` with `F B` equal to `T`. As an extreme case, suppose we have

```
type instance F _ = ()
```

Then if we took our guess `x1 :: T1 (F a) -> a`, we'd have

```
T1 :: a -> T1 ()
x1 :: T1 () -> b
```

and composing these would let us write `a -> b`, which is bad.

The real type of `x1` is something like an existential-providing-constraint

```
T1 t -> (exists a. (F a ~ t) *> a)
```

which GHC doesn't support.

The issue with `T3` is effectively the same as if you had

```
data T3' where T3' :: { x3' :: a } -> T3'
```

You can extract the field with a pattern match (which might be useful if there were more fields or a constraint), but not with a record selector or function.